# Request to api server(Golang) via nginx failed and returned 404 error

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, nginx

I'm setting up nginx in docker environment.
When I try to access to api server via nginx port, request returns 404 error.

Here is the stack.

```
・client: react/axios
・api: golang/gin
・web server: nginx
・db: mysql
・container: docker
・ci-tool: travis
・deploy: aws elastic beanstalk
```

Entire source code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

```
article
  ├ client
  │  └ nginx
  │      └ default.conf
  ├ api
  ├ nginx
  │   └ default.conf
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

Here is `docker-compose.yml`.

```
//docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
    depends_on:
      - client
      - api
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_HOST
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

Here is `default.conf`.

```
//default.conf
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:2345;
}

server {
  listen 80;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://client;
}

location /sockjs-node {
  proxy_pass http://client;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}

location /api {
  rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

Also there is `default.conf` in client.

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I expect nginx reverse proxy to port 2345 api server.
But the actual returns 404 response.

```
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:06 +0000] "GET /static/js/bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:07 +0000] "GET /static/js/0.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:07 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:07 +0000] "GET /static/js/bundle.js.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:08 +0000] "GET /static/js/0.chunk.js.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:08 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.chunk.js.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
api_1     | [GIN] 2019/08/09 - 22:19:09 | 404 |      41.937µs |      172.23.0.5 | GET      /articles
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:09 +0000] "GET /api/articles HTTP/1.1" 404 18 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:10 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1565389150444 HTTP/1.1" 200 90 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1   | 172.23.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019:22:19:10 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Also when accessing to actual deployed url, it returns `502 Bad Gateway` now.
http://multidocker-env.vwnrixavuv.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/articles

Comment: I think you have wrongly used `rewrite` directive, to truncate `/api/` prefix before forwarding request to your `gin` app, however your `gin` app does include the `api` prefix.

Comment: I thought `api := router.Group("/api")` indicates `/api/` for api request.

Comment: yes, but the url `/api/ariticles` have been rewrite to `/articles` before passing to `gin`. The last fourth line in your log have told you that `gin` could not found path for `/articles`.

Comment: Issue is resolved by removing `rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Enix suggested on comment, after removing `rewrite` directive, issue is resolved.

`rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;`